# Error SqlException: Invalid object name '@p0 happening when I run ExecuteSql in my .net core project, but the query looks fine

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

Some background, I have a database that holds Organizations and that table has a field that tells me a database name. That database name is used to look up OrgUnits which exist on another database. I need to look this up because there are many databases involved and it changes based on the Organization.

I have tried running this query a couple of different ways and every time it is not making it to SQL and executing correctly. I can't even really find similar errors searching online so it is confusing because I know others have run into this before.

Here are a couple different attempts with the same result. I have also tried changing my DB context.

```
        var orgUnits = _context.Organizations.FromSqlInterpolated($"SELECT * FROM [{orgForDBName.DbCatalog}].dbo.OrgUnits WHERE OrgId = {devices.OrgId}").ToList();

        var orgUnits = _context.Organizations.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM [{0}].dbo.OrgUnits WHERE OrgId = {1}", orgForDBName.DbCatalog, devices.OrgId).ToList();
```

I have put together this test string and it looks like good SQL which executes fine when I run it in SQL Management Studio:

```
string test = $"SELECT * FROM [{devices.Organizations.DbCatalog}].dbo.OrgUnits WHERE OrgId = {devices.OrgId}";
```

Why would the SQL query run fine with my "test" string, but I cannot execute it with the FromSql methods? I keep getting this error:

SqlException: Invalid object name '@p0.dbo.OrgUnits'.

Comment: Maybe you need to use 'USE DatabaseName; Go' in the query.

Comment: You can't have object names as parameters in SQL. So no database names, no table names, no schema names, no column names, and so on. You'll need dynamic SQL to do what you want, not parametrized SQL. That said, if you do use dynamic SQL, beware of SQL injection and guard your code against it.

Comment: Oh wow. OK. Thank you for the education. Any suggestion for doing this a different way based on my scenario where my lookup for my dropdown depends on a previous dropdown? AND the lookup also depends on which server is selected based on a value in the previous dropdown?

Comment: I figured out a better way to change database context on each time I make a method call. Also, for other parts of my code I am going to use stored procedures and have to convince the DB admin to let me add them at some point.